# Mouse press event called twice

Tags: mouseevent, processing

The following code is not working properly, what i want to happen is to call the placing_shapes_in_screen function with a mouse press and then wait for another press to place an object on the screen, however what is actually happening is that the first key press is registering twice!! please help?

```
boolean cont = false;

void setup(){
    size(500,400);
    background(0,0,53);
}  

void draw(){
    if(mousePressed){
    placing_shapes_in_screen();
    println("done");
    }
}


void placing_shapes_in_screen(){

    fill(204,0,102);
    text("Hello", 60, 90);
    noFill();  

    while(cont == false){    
    if(mousePressed){
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,20,20);
    cont=true;
    }
    }
    cont=false;

}
```

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman The language is Processing.

Comment: @Ossama Where do you declare and initialize the `cont` variable?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. What do you mean when you say that the first key press is registering twice? The `draw()` function is called 60 times per second, so as long as the mouse is held down, I would expect your `placing_shapes_in_screen()` function to be called continuously. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Thanks, I want the second mouse press to be separate to the first.

Comment: so basically, when i press the mouse button it takes me to the function and then waits again for another mouse press to draw the ellipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the issue is that by default draw is called 60 time each second. That makes relying in the var `mousePressed` to control user interaction, not very precise, perhaps the button was still pressed, 1/60th seconds later...

The way to go is to use the function [`mousePressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/mousePressed.html)  or [`mouseClicked()`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html) that are  callback functions called once when one of those events ocour.

some thing like this:

```
void mousePressed(){
place_shapes_in_screen();
}


void place_shapes_in_screen(){
fill(204,0,102);
text("Hello", 60, 90);
noFill();   
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,20,20);

}
```

**edit to answer OP's comment:**

Than you need to check if the mouse is inside the button, and a flag (or program states) to handle placing the ellipse.

in kind of pseudo code:

```
boolean okToPlace = false;



void mousePressed(){
    if(mouseIsInsideButton()){
        okToPlace = true;
        }else if (okToPlace){
        place_shapes_in_screen()
    }

}

void place_shapes_in_screen(){
    fill(204,0,102); 
    text("Hello", 60, 90);
    noFill();   
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,20,20);
    okToPlace = false; // <<<<<<<<<!!
}
```

**edit2**

here a working one online at sketchpad.cc[here](http://sketchpad.cc/CWRPOyJCzz):

```
boolean okToPlace = false;
PVector button;


void setup(){
    size(300,300);
    //using z for size
    button = new PVector(20, height-40, 20);

    }


void draw(){

    color f = isInsideButton()? color(255,0,0):color(0,0,255);
   fill(f);
    rect(button.x, button.y, button.z, button.z);    
    }




void mousePressed(){
    if(isInsideButton()){
        okToPlace = true;
        }else if(okToPlace){
            ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80,80);
            okToPlace = false;
            }
    }


boolean isInsideButton(){
    return mouseX > button.x &&
           mouseX < button.x+button.z &&
           mouseY > button.y &&
           mouseY < button.y + button.z;
    }
```

Comment: I have a bunch of buttons and really would like to modify my code to work, I want to allow for 2 mouse presses, 1 when pressing a button and another to select the location of the ellipse

Answer (score 0):

> I want the second mouse press to be separate to the first.

Consider using the `mousePressed()` function instead of the `mousePressed` variable. Something like this:

```
void setup(){
 background(0); 
}

void draw() {}

void mousePressed() {
   println("Mouse pressed.");
   ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

The `mousePressed` variable is simply true whenever the mouse is held down, so you don't get separate **events** for different clicks. The `mousePressed()` function is only called **once** per mouse click though, so you can separate different clicks into different events.

Note that there are other event functions such as `mouseReleased()` and `mouseClicked()`. You can check them out in [the Processing reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/).

Comment: I have a bunch of buttons and really would like to modify my code to work, I want to allow for 2 mouse presses, 1 when pressing a button and another to select the location of the ellipse

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking, and that sounds like a separate question. If you have on-screen buttons, then you have to detect **where** your mouse has been clicked and determine whether it's inside one of those buttons. There are libraries that handle that stuff for you.

Comment: thanks, i thought the question was clear, 1 button press to activate the button and another to select the location of the ellipse. I thought this maybe a simple task, you are right, 1 mouse press does get registered multiple times, not sure how to solve this

Comment: I still don't know what you mean when you say that one mouse press gets registered twice. What happens when you run the code I posted?

Comment: I don't want to draw the ellipse on top of the button, I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: @Ossama Sorry, but it doesn't. What button are you talking about? Again, you might have to check the position of the mouse, or keep track of how many times the mouse has been clicked. Try something out and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.